# jenkins pipeline error No compiler is provided in this environment Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, devops

I am using Amazon ec2 Linux server. I am getting the following error in the Jenkins pipeline output.

```
No compiler is provided in this environment Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK
```

I tried to run the command on the server and its working well. I have updated JDK and MVN installation to my linux path in the global tool configuration but I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do one more step. Open Jenkins, Locate "Manage Jenkins", click "Global Tool configuration", click "JDK installations", and under JDK set the JAVA_HOME to your JDK path.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ranjithkr's answer, you need to add JAVA_HOME under the environment variables section in Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties. This needs to be done after adding the JDK in Global tools configuration.

Comment: Thanks Max, above solution indeed worked. Not sure but setting JAVA_HOME env variable is required for a 'Pipeline' type job, but equivalent job configuration worked with 'Freestyle' job without creating env var, not sure why? Please share if you've more insight on this.